# How to adjust divs to decrease their size as you add new sister divs?

Tags: html, css

I need a parent div to occupy the entire width of the screen and when adding child divs inside the parent div, the child divs will decrease the width so that they all fit inside the parent div without having scrool.
Equal behavior of browsers when adding new tabs.[tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRTao.png)

Comment: display: flex on the parent for flex-shrink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `display: flex;` on the container. The default `flex-shrink` will handle the rest:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

/* for visualization only */
.container {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  height: 50px;
}

.container > div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button>Click me to add an Element</button>
```

Comment: This one lacks the ability to have the element take the full width when there are a small number of elements.

Comment: @brober that was not asked. But you can sue flex-grow or set the width of the child elements to 100%. But again that was not asked. The question is about tabs that should shrink if to many are added to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is with `display: table`. It works in current modern browsers.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
}
#one {
  background-color:green
}
#two {
  background-color:blue
}
#three {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
  <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div> 
</div>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/dokve351/

Comment: while this solves the issue I would state missing simplicity on this one. `flexbox` solves the issue with one line over your 3 lines and it is supported by all browsers aswell.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
.parent{
display : flex-shrink;
}
.child{
width : auto
max-width : 100px;
min-width : 10%;
}
```

Thats with basic CSS, if you are using React there will be an easier code.

Comment: `display: flex-shrink` is an invalid value for that property. It does not exsist. `flex-shrink` is an own property but not a value for the `display`-property. Also, `width: auto max-width...` will output an error too because of the missing semicolon.

Comment: sure. i see. thanks for the insght